# Solving Matrices with more than 3 variables gives bad results

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

## Solving Matrices with more than 3 variables gives bad results

This is a very weird problem that probably have a really simple solution.

### Background information:

So I am making a thermometer using an Arduino measuring the resistance of a thermistor. I need to make sure that I only use one probe, and I want to be accurate to 0.1°C

The temperature can be found with the help of this model called the Steinhart-hart equation:
$$
    \frac{1}{T}=\sum_{i=0}^{n} C_{i}\cdot \ln^i{R} \qquad
    ([1], pg\space2)
$$
Where:
T = Temperature in Kelvin
n  = Number of times you want to repeat the thing, and thus also the number of coefficients you need
C<sub>i</sub> = Steinhart-hart coefficients which vary for different values of i
R = Resistance in Ω

and when you expand it looks like:
$$
  \frac{1}{T}= A +B\cdot\ln{R}+C\cdot\ln^2{R}+D\cdot\ln^3{R} \space....
$$
A, B, C is I guess just a different way to write C<sub>i</sub>
The guys who figured out this equation figured out that after $i=3$, the coefficients make a really small contribution to the equation, and $i=4$ also makes a negligible difference to the equation, so they say that you can write the equation as:
$$
\frac{1}{T}= A +B\cdot\ln{R}+C\cdot\ln^3{R} 
$$
If you are wondering what the negligible difference was I think it was something like 0.0025K, but I do not have a citation for that but it was pretty small.

So the Coefficients vary among different resistors, and so before you make the final product, you need to calibrate the thermistor, by finding 3 resistances with their corresponding temperatures, and make a system of equations and solving for it. With computers you would want to write the system of equations as a matrix. The matrix looks like this:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{T_1}\\
\frac{1}{T_2}\\
\frac{1}{T_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B\\
C
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \ln(R_1)  & \ln^3(R_1) \\ 
1 & \ln(R_2)  & \ln^3(R_2) \\ 
1 & \ln(R_3)  & \ln^3(R_3) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then you would feed in the Rs and the Ts and get your coefficients, and thus a good model.
So... I think that concludes the background information about my problem.

### Problem

I decided to calibrate my thermistor with 16 points instead of 3 points.
Wait... Didn't you say that you only need 3 points to calibrate the thermistor, and after 3 points the difference is negligible?
Well, yes but if I used more points to calibrate the thermistor, then I will be able to have all my data points fit the curve and affect the main Coefficients, which will make my model stronger.
So I got 16 points which are:
Temp in °C (Note that the model uses Kelvin):
`{0.7,2.0,5.3,8.06,9.95,14.82,20.4,29.6,41.0,49.1,53.9,60.0,65.0,70.0,74.4,78.3}`
Resistance in Ω:
`{22976.98,21263.83,17935,15690.9,14003.87,11851.83,9262.09,6926.95,4575.89,3430.07,2987.74,2436.42,2070.49,1806.5,1489.12,1349.3}`
Just to show why I wanted a better curve, here is a scatter plot with Temperature in °C on the y axis and Resistance in Ω on the x axis.

[image: SCatterPlot]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/scatterPlot.png))</sub>

Then I used 3 reasonable points: index(from 1): 2, 9 and 14 to calibrate the A, B, and C values, and then plotted the function and here is the graph with the residual plot:

[image: Residuals]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/residuals.png))</sub>

as you see, the |residuals| range from 0.98 to 2.273, which is not a good sight, as that is just not accurate.

#### Getting to the point:

So I wrote a program to loop for each t and r value and programmatically create a matrix, and then solve both sides:
I also added a feature where you can add a variable for the number of coefficients you want to calibrate, and it uses that many random indices, selects corresponding temp and res values, makes the matrices and prints them, so that I can double-check that they are making the correct matrices and I did double-check the matrices that are made. Then the program solves the matrices.  [Here is a link](https://github.com/Sanjit1/detectorBuildingBadMath/blob/master/main.py) to the program.
When I use 3 as the number of coefficients, then I get reasonable looking graphs for the scatter plot:

[image: 3 point]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/coeff3.png))</sub>

But when I try to use 4 as the number of coefficients, then sometimes I get good data, other times I do not:

[image: Good 4 coeff]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/goodcoeff4.png))</sub>

[image: Bad 4 coeff]

But when I start increasing the number of coefficients wierd stuff start happening, and some plots do not even have the data points themselves in them, like whaaa...:

[image: 5 coeff]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/coeff5.png))</sub>

[image: 7 coeff]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/coeff7.png))</sub>

[image: 10 coeff]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/coeff10.png))</sub>

[image: 15 coeff]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/coeff15.png))</sub>

[image: 16 coeff]
<sub>(source: [sanjit.wtf](https://sanjit.wtf/detectorBuildingBadMath/coeff16.png))</sub>

.

### Conclusion:

My question is why is this happening? Is it a problem with the matricies?

#### Citations

There is only one but ok:
[Temperature Measurement in Dimensional Metrology – Why the SteinhartHart Equation works so well](https://web.archive.org/web/20190706175829/http://www.macroscale.org/proceedings/2011/8_2011_Matus__M.pdf)

And finally Thank you, for even looking at my question.

[image]

Comment: Only a comment since I have not read your question thoroughly. If your calculation with $16$ points means you are trying to find more constants in your model and the last $13$ of them are very small then your matrix arithmetic may be numerically unstable. Someplace you could be dividing by a number near $0$, or introducing roundoff errors that skew the results.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I did not really know that, ill double check and see whats happening, but if that is the case do you know any way around it with using more than 3 variables?

Comment: There is substantial literature about making matrix calculations robustly, but I can't point you to it. Your data points have three significant digits. It may follow that you don't really have enough information to calculate all the small constants you are looking for. Casual first thought: do you see anything useful if you calculate the first three coefficients of your model using several sets of three of your measurements?

Comment: I updated my question to properly show the pictures of graphs. So as I said, using several sets of 3 points, I got pretty good curves, that have the same shape as my scatterplot, but I get pretty big residuals when I do so. Also addressing your first comment I do not think that the model starts dividing with 0 until like 7 or 8 points because until then it is just a curve that does not look anything like my scatterplot.

Comment: It looks like a bug really, because when it breaks it's not even a function anymore.

Comment: Do you mean a bug in the code? What do you mean by break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking a bit at your code and how it works, when I set the number_of_coefficients to 16, the program solves for 16 coefficients in your equation. This is the problem: the later variables are all negligible. Your program should not have been solving for any higher variables.

You are treating this as an interpolation problem, where it should not be. Interpolation, as you're using it, is the process of finding equations that will pass through a given set of points. What is happening here is that your list of coefficients solves for a curve that literally passes through each data point instead of finding a simple best fit curve. That would explain the mangled curves.

The reason why it might ordinarily be useful to solve a linear system for A,B, and C with only three data points is because it locates the only triplet that can pass through all three points, and this gives a nice approximation for your curve. However, with more data points, the new goal should be optimizing A,B, and C to best fit with the data, instead of introducing new variables.

The solution to your problem would require scratching the linear algebra solver in favor of some sort of regression method. I'm not too familiar with how you would do that in detail, but at least we've figured out the cause of the odd curves. Good luck!